# MySQL: INSERT and SELECT in same query

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have tricky `SQL` query to create, which if possible will save me a lot of PHP code.

So I have an HTML form where a visitor can create a user account with the fields **name**, **email**, **password**, **interests**.

For the **name**, **email** and **password** I have a simple `INSERT` query to enter this info into the database `users`, however the **interests** field can have multiple entries so this data is stored in many-to-many join tables (`interests`, `user_interests`).

In order for me enter these interests in the table **user_interests**, I need to obtain the User ID number which was auto-incremented from the initial `INSERT` query plus loop over another INSERT for each "interest" the user has chosen. Can I accomplish this all in one SQL query?

Comment: You'll have to use 2 queries or a transaction. The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will be useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Probably yes, using INSERT INTO (cols. . .) SELECT cols. . . FROM . . ., but you'll need to state what information is in what tables when you want to execute this SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in MySQL an INSERT statement only inserts into one table. So no, it's impossible to accomplish this with a single query. But you can do it with two queries. MySQL supports a syntax where you can insert multiple rows with a single query:

```
insert into user_interests (user_id, interest_id) values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)
```

P.S. I do understand correctly that the interests are a classifier, and adding new rows to the `interests` table is beyond the scope of this question, right?

Comment: Oracle has a way to insert into more than one table with a single INSERT: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2125362

Comment: Ahh, well then, I take my words back. :P

Comment: That's correct, the interests table is a set number of choices the user can select.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with one command, then it sounds like a good case to learn how to write MySql stored procedures. The result will be much faster too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-last-insert-id.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html

Comment: And how do you intend to pass a list of ID's to the stored procedure? Perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't find any array-like datatypes in the MySQL manual.

Comment: I would pass it as a comma separated list, then parse out the data and build a single insert statement with multiple rows. There are definitely MySql functions to easily do that. Learning how to write SP is one of the most valuable skills in programming, because they are universal across all languages (you just call them with parameters)

Comment: more hints:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop-statement.html  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,235478,235683#msg-235683